# Angular http client post call giving 404 error

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have asp.net core web api running on my local and I am able to make the request using post method through Postman. But when i do it using httpclient in angular in following manner, its returning 404.

```
import { HttpClientModule,HttpClient,HttpHeaders,HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

var headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");  
var content = { "testParam":"testvalue" };

    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:50979/api/test",JSON.stringify(content),{ headers: headers }).subscribe(
      data => {
          console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
      }
    );
```

So what is the wrong with this code ? My api is running fine and i am able to get the data correctly using postman. Get request works fine using httpclient.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture from the postman call ?

Comment: If it works with Postman but not with angular, you do not send the same request. I'd double check your angular request in your browsers dev tools. And I think you don't want to JSON.stringify the request body. Angular should do this for you. Does it return bad request or 404?

Comment: @Mhand7: added above.Thanks

Comment: @ChristophLütjen: its 404. Changed the title of the question. Thanks. Yes,stringify is not required.In the dev tool, I am not able to see the request payload. If I omit the headers in the request, it shows request payload but returns 400

Comment: @TiagoNeiva: Its logging error in the console. Question is whats wrong in the request from Postman and from Angular.

Comment: are the headers the same in postman and in Angular?, could you show us your headers in postman?

Comment: did you add  CORS and some Origins Exceptions on server side?

Comment: @hjbello, yes,both are same. I have added header snapshot from Postman above

Comment: @TiagoNeiva: yes I am allowing any headers,any oigin and method.                       services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(86400));
                });
            });

Comment: I guess you're using "testParam" somewhere in your route. In angular you do not send a json structure but just a string (due to json.stringify). That's why there's no parameter and that's why there is no route for it. You can see the request payload in all browsers, so read about it and double check.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen: you have rightly said. I am not using "testParam" anywhere though.I just omitted all the parameters and tried post without body so it was 200. I tried to accept a value as string,object and dynamic but it did not work. Anyways thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a CORS issue, please check the console or errors to see if any CORS related issue.

https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing but..

1) ensure your request body is correct

```
// correct request body
{ "testParam": "foo" }

// WRONG, we don't want a string!!!
"{ testParam... }"
```

https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2016/09/view-post-data-using-chrome-developer-tools/

2) Ensure you have no CORS problem, you will see errors telling you something about "OPTIONS" requests. You can inspect that in dev tools > network too.

3) Read post body in asp core, this should look like this

```
 public Task MyAction([FromBody] MyRequest myModel) { … }

 // where… 
 public class MyRequest {
   public string TestParam {get; set;}
 }
```